# Is there a point to using a with statement for creating a stem.control.Controller object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stem

I have some python that talks to a tor daemon, here it tells the daemon to shut down.

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def shutDownTor():
    with Controller.from_port(port=portNum) as controller:
        controller.signal(Signal.SHUTDOWN)
```

I'm using a `with` statement because the code I'm <s>stealing from</s> learning from does so too. The code works fine, but I'm wondering if there is any point to using the `with` statement.

I know that when you use `with` to open files it makes sure the file closes even if there's an `Exception` or interrupt. But in this case it seems like all `with` is doing is adding an un-necessary tab. The variable `controller` is even left inside the namespace.

Comment: "The variable controller is even left inside the namespace."  ?

Comment: Your understanding of what `with` is doing is just one very specific use case. `with` doesn't "open and close files"

Comment: In order to fully understand what `with` is doing *here*, one will have to read the implementation of `Controller.from_signal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Controller` class you import from `stem` is a [wrapper](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html) for `ControlSocket` which is itself a [wrapper around a socket connection](https://stem.torproject.org/api/socket.html#stem.socket.ControlSocket) to Tor protocol. So when you use `with` in your code, you do so to open a connection with the given port. The same way the `file` is open and closed, you will have to open and close the connection yourself if you want to get rid of `with`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to *get rid of* the `with` statement you will have to handle all of the `open`,`close` and `exception` on your own.

This will results with:

```
  try:
    controller = Controller.from_port()
  except stem.SocketError as exc:
    print("Unable to connect to tor on port 9051: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)
  finally:
      controller.close()
```

Which results with the same and I will quote "un-necessary tab".

You can skip all of it (handle the `close`, `open` and `exception`) if you are aware of and ready for all the **consequences** of it.